# How to style <select> with bottom border and caret?

Tags: html, css, select

How can i style the Select element to look like it is in the image? I'm struggling to get both down caret and line to appear at the same time. 
I've tried playing around with setting a `border-bottom: 1px` and then setting `-webkit-appearance: none` but the caret disappears.

[image: Select Dropdown]

```css
select {
 border: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would set `border-bottom` and not `bottom-border`, it doesn't exist in css

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake when I was typing the question. I've edited my question with a code snippet now.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the *"clean sheet"* or `all: unset` to remove all predefined *styles* of the `select` *element*, then *style* it as desired:

```css
select {
  all: unset; 
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  background: url('https://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/9662') no-repeat right;
  background-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>All Question Types</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-bottom
font-family
```

I think that's all you will really need to change to make it more like the example you've shown

Comment: Sorry the border-bottom was a mistake when i wrote out the stack question.

Comment: Gotcha. W3 schools has a great tutorial on customizing the whole menu to make it as pretty as you want, I would reccomend checking that out!